# MKMapView NSInvalidArgumentException Invalid Region crash in ios

Tags: ios5, mapkit

I am getting the error  "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid Region ' " in my piece of code.This is the code:

```
- (MKCoordinateRegion)region
{
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = (maxLat + 90) - (minLat + 90);
    span.longitudeDelta = (maxLon + 180) - (minLon + 180);

    NSLog(@"value of lat delta %f",span.latitudeDelta);
    NSLog(@"value of long delta %f",span.longitudeDelta);

    if(span.latitudeDelta == 0.0f)
    span.latitudeDelta = 0.1f;
    if(span.longitudeDelta == 0.0f)
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.1f;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
    center.latitude = minLat + span.latitudeDelta / 2;
    center.longitude = minLon + span.longitudeDelta / 2;

    return MKCoordinateRegionMake(center, span);
}
```

Here the center.latitude and center.longitude are getting zero and its getting crashed.
values for maxlat, maxlon, minlat and minlon are 
maxLat = -91, minLat =  91, maxLon = -181, minLon =  181
Kindly help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. Plotting the max (lat, long) and min (lat, long) on google maps, basically throws it out of bounds. (and this I guess is not handled gracefully in MapKit in iOS 6)

For now, the fix I have in place (and it works) is to set these values
maxLat = -75, minLat = 75, maxLon = -175, minLon = 175

My app can afford to do this, since its mostly plotting the map for some of the most densely populated areas. If your map has to show the whole planet including the north/south poles, then I am not sure if my hack will help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and investigated that the maximimum values of the the latitude and longtitude can be set to: 
 **minLat**  = -84  **maxLat**  = 84
 **minLong** = -179 **maxLong** = 179
otherwise your location will be out of the bounds of the map and calling setRegion can cause crash.